# Existential proof:$\forall x>0, \exists y>0$ $ s.t. $ $x/y>2$

Tags: inequality, quantifiers

This is taken to be for all reals.
I figure the statement is true if we let y be some value $<1/2$ $x$, since $1 /0.5=2$. I just seem to be struggling with how to formulate a proof. Any sort of help would be appreciated

Comment: I think you could use one of the axioms of the reals (Archimedes).

Comment: @T_M: You don't need Archimedes' axiom, as Nikolay Gromov's answer shows.

Comment: One not needing something and one not using something aren't really the same things. @TonyK

Comment: @T_M: That doesn't mean that my comment is wrong, or that I was wrong to post it.

Comment: Nor was my first comment... @TonyK

Comment: @T_M: So we're good, right?

Answer (score 1):

if $x$ is real $x/3$ is also real so take $y=x/3$